# Django 2.2 with 2 domains

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web app and 2 domains. I want to use these domains for the different Django apps.

For example:

- firstdomain.com -> stuff app
- seconddomain.com -> customer app

Is it possible? How should urls.py looks like?

Answer (score 3):

> Django comes with an optional “sites” framework. It’s a hook for associating objects and functionality to particular websites, and it’s a holding place for the domain names and “verbose” names of your Django-powered sites.
> **Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.**

[The "sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)